# Python - Regex replace a character only if after a pattern

Tags: python, regex

I have a lot of strings with this pattern `[INTEGER]-[URL-SLUG]`. Examples:

```
234234-url-slug-1
2-urlslug2
301-url-slug4
```

I need to replace the '-' after the integer with a '/' but leave the other '-' intact. So final strings would be:

```
234234/url-slug-1
2/urlslug2
301/url-slug4
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: [`(?<=\d)-` click to try](https://regex101.com/r/B25nhB/1)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[***re.sub***](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) function has the optional argument *count* which is the maximum number of pattern occurrences to be replaced:

```
s = '234234-url-slug-1'
result = re.sub(r'^(\d+)-', r'\1/', s, 1)

print(result)
```

The output:

```
234234/url-slug-1
```

Answer (score 2):

This should work using [`re.sub`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub):

```
> import re

> s = '234234-url-slug-1'
> re.sub(r'(\d)\-', r'\1/', s)
'234234/url-slug-1'
```

`\1` in the replacement string refers to the first captured group in the matching pattern: `'(\d)'`.